# How to improve TreeView using Converter, UI freeze

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a TreeView in xaml, I implement it just like the Windows file explorer

```
<UserControl.Resources>

    <logic:GetFileSysemInformationConverter x:Key="getFileSysemInformationConverter"/>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type md:DirInfo}" 
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Converter={StaticResource getFileSysemInformationConverter}}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Width="20" Height="20" Stretch="Fill" x:Name="img" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="5,0,0,0" />
        </StackPanel>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=DirType}" Value="0">
                <Setter Property="Image.Source" TargetName="img" Value="/Images/mycomputer.jpg"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=DirType}" Value="1">
                <Setter Property="Image.Source" TargetName="img" Value="/Images/diskdrive.png"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=DirType}" Value="2">
                <Setter Property="Image.Source" TargetName="img" Value="/Images/folder.png"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=DirType}" Value="99">
                <Setter Property="Image.Source" TargetName="img" Value="/Images/favorite.jpg"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
        <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <EventSetter Event="Expanded" Handler="fileTree_Expanded"></EventSetter>
    </Style>

</UserControl.Resources>
```

I use a converter to auto-bindi to the value.
This causes the UI to freeze:

```
public class GetFileSysemInformationConverter : IValueConverter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Data context
    /// </summary>
    protected ExplorerDBContext ExplorerDBContext
    {
        get { return _explorerDBContext.Value; }
    }
    Lazy<ExplorerDBContext> _explorerDBContext = new Lazy<ExplorerDBContext>();

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {
            var nodeToExpand = value as DirInfo;
            if (nodeToExpand == null)
                return null;

            //return the subdirectories of the Current Node
            if ((ObjectType)nodeToExpand.DirType == ObjectType.MyComputer)
            {
                return (from sd in FileTreeService.GetRootDirectories()
                        select new DirInfo(sd)).ToList();
            }
            else if ((ObjectType)nodeToExpand.DirType == ObjectType.Farovate)
            {
                return ExplorerDBContext.Favorites
                    .Select(r => new DirInfo
                    {
                        Name = r.Name,
                        Path = r.Path,
                        DirType = r.Type,
                        Root = r.Root
                    }).ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                return (from dir in FileTreeService.GetChildDirectories(nodeToExpand.Path)
                        select new DirInfo(dir)).ToList();
            }

        }
        catch { return null; }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

With a low-end computer this blocks the UI.
Is there a way I can improve this code, or should I stop using a converter.

This is my FileTreeServiec

```
 public static IEnumerable<FileInfo> GetChildFiles(string directory)
    {
        try
        {
            var fileInfo = (from x in Directory.GetFiles(directory)
                            select new FileInfo(x));

            return fileInfo
                .Where(r => (r.Attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) == 0);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        return new List<FileInfo>();
    }
```

Comment: I suggest not to do so much "logic" in the Converter.Reading from your DBContext from your converter raises a red flag IMHO. Rather build up your data soure _before binding_ and then set your ItemsSource to your built up hierarchy. **A converter should only be used to format bound data!**

Comment: If it is code you have written, can you post up your code for the "FileTreeService"?  As Niels says, you have way too much going on in a converter and being on the UI thread, it will cause the UI freeze.

Comment: It is the responsibility of your `ViewModel` to get the data that your `TreeView` needs to bind to. In theory, you shouldn't need a converter at all.

Comment: @JamesHarcourt I already put my FileTreeService code, I think you are right, I need to change to using bind, not converter...